# File permissions of file when tranferring from Windows to Unix

Tags: permissions

When I am uploading a file from windows PC to Unix ,the permissions of file are `--wxr----t` on unix machine , whereas umask is `0022` .I am not able to understand from where is the file getting permissions `--wxr----t` ?

Please help me understand.

Comment: Can you specify how exactly are you uploading the files?

Comment: I am uploading the files via `total commander` tool. As per my information ,there is some file in unix that handles ftp umask.I am not able to find out what that file is.

Comment: And what's on the Unix side? What FTP (or other) server?

Comment: That looks like a bug: those permissions (1341) don't make any sense, and the t bit wouldn't arise naturally from some mangled Windows permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which ftpd you are using on the Unix side and there are a few to choose from. The [BSD derived ftpd says](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpd) it's an option to the daemon:

> **-u umask**
>   Sets the umask for the ftpd process. The default value is normally 027.

The [Total Commander FAQ](http://www.ghisler.com/efaqftp.htm#permissions) says:

> **Q**: How can I change the access rights (permissions) of files?
>   **A**: If the FTP server supports the chmod command (unfortunately not supported by all servers), you can either use the function Files - Change attributes, or directly send the command through the command line, e.g. SITE chmod 755 test.cgi

But the odd part is the sticky-bit `t` being set which is probably the fault of Total Commander because a umask only strips out bits and it is the rare file that should have that bit set to start with.

You don't say if you are wedded to Total Commander, but is there a compelling reason to not use [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) `scp` or even mount the source volume on the destination machine via [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29)? FTP is a tad [outdated](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

Comment: It is not really about what method to choose for copying.I am just trying to find the cause of those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about total commander but I recall using Transmit on osx and you could specify default settings for what permissions it would upload a file with. I think it was dependant on server settings also allowing chmod commands.

See if the total commander settings specify default permissions.

Or is it copying/generating permissions based on the windows permissions?